# Разделитель строки на ФИО (без регулярных выражений) JAVA

Tags: java

ФИО должно состоять только из букв и символа дефис (в случае двойного имени/фамилии/отчества). Никаких других символов не должно допускаться.
Не могу понять как сделать проверку, **НЕЛЬЗЯ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ РЕГУЛЯРНЫЕ ВЫРАЖЕНИЯ.**
(единственное что нашёл это hasNextInt, чтобы отсечь числа);

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
      System.out.println("Введенная строка не является ФИО");
    } else {
      String name = scanner.nextLine();
      if (name.equals(" ")) {
        System.out.println("Введенная строка не является ФИО");
      }

      int count = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isWhitespace(name.charAt(i))) count++;
      }

      if (count > 2) {
        System.out.println("Введенная строка не является ФИО");
      } else {
        if (count == 0) {
          System.out.println("Введенная строка не является ФИО");
        } else {
          int familyIndex = name.indexOf(' ');
          int nameIndex = name.lastIndexOf(' ');

          String familyIndex1 = name.substring(0, familyIndex).trim();
          System.out.println("Фамилия: " + familyIndex1);
          String nameIndex1 = name.substring(familyIndex, nameIndex).trim();
          String patronymicIndex = name.substring(nameIndex).trim();

          if (nameIndex1.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Имя: " + patronymicIndex);
            System.out.println("У человека нет отчества");
          } else {
            System.out.println("Имя: " + nameIndex1);
            System.out.println("Отчество: " + patronymicIndex);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Считываете строку, потом проверяйте каждый символ на соответствие требованиям. Каждый символ - это числовой код. Вот и проверяйте попадания числа в нужный диапазон.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант решения без регулярных выражений:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isName("Иванов Иван Иванович")); // true
    System.out.println(isName("Петров Петр Петрович")); // true
    System.out.println(isName("Сидоров-Фёдоров Сидор Фёдорович")); // true
    System.out.println(isName("48 Попугаев")); // false
    System.out.println(isName("McDonald's")); // false
}

public static boolean isName(String name) {
    char[] chars = name.toCharArray();
    for (char ch : chars) {
        // если хотябы один символ не буква, не дефис и не пробел
        if (!Character.isLetter(ch) &&  ch != '-' && ch != ' ') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

Вариант решения с использованием [`String.chars`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#chars--), тоже без регулярных выражений:

```java
public static boolean isName(String name) {
    return name
            // получаем IntStream
            // по символам строки
            .chars()
            // если символ не буква, не дефис и не пробел
            .filter(ch -> !Character.isLetter(ch) && ch != '-' && ch != ' ')
            // таких символов быть не должно
            .count() == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Очень размытые требования. Можно например так: только буквы, пробелы и дефис.

```
String fio = ...;

for (Char c: fio) {
    if (c.isLetter() || c == '-' || c == ' ') {
        continue;
    } else {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Not valid fio");
    }
}
```

Однако, такое пропустит всякое типа      `tetsбе-бе-бе`